# is it possible to update collection name dynamically in cloud firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a collection name based on the date like i have a collection name like this Change 06-05-2020 and i want to overwrite this collection daily and make the collection name like this Change 07-05-2020 and so on is it possible to do it i ma creating the collection in this way.and basically i am trying to store the daily updated data in a particular way so i can track that information.so can i update the collection name dynamically daily?

```
await growthfilemsdb.collection(`Change${getISO8601Date()}`).doc(change.after.data().officeId).set(change.after.data(),{merge:false})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the name of a collection.  What you can do instead is simply copy all the documents from the old collection to a new one with a new name.

However, it's usually not a good idea to make the names of your collection dynamic like this.  Instead, consider putting the date as a field inside the document, and using that to filter the results of queries or delete old documents.